# How to know if raphael object is hidden?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am creating a diagram application in which I hide and show few elements e.g.

```
var c = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
c.hide()

var c2 = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
c2.show()
```

Now I want to act upon such shapes e.g. calculate bounding box etc but I am not able to find how to get if shape is hidden or not? Is there something like this shape.is_visible() or shape.attr('visible')

Comment: this really ought to be in the raphael api, can't believe we have to implement it ourselves

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I took a look at the documentation and source code and cooked this up (untested):

```
Raphael.el.is_visible = function() {
    return (this.node.style.display !== "none");
}
```

Call as follows:

```
var c = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
c.hide();
if (c.is_visible())
    alert("Visible");
else
    alert("Invisible");
```

Comment: +1 for exactly doing what I am doing ;)  Raphael.el.is_hidden = function () {
    return  this.node.style.display == 'none'
};