# how to raphael.serialize only visible elements?

Tags: javascript, raphael

i would like to serialize only visible elements on my paper.

i have done some research about checking if an element is visible or not andi found an answer on [How to know if raphael object is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222778/how-to-know-if-raphael-object-is-hidden)

i changed raphael.serialize.js file and on line 16 i made this change:

```
if (node && node.type) {
```

to

```
if (node && node.type && node.style.display !== "none") {
```

but in this way i get null content.

how can i get this working?

update:
what i need is to convert a paper to svg. based on: http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/06/04/export-svg-from-raphael-js-to-create-a-png-bitmap/

Comment: Based on what you said, this makes sense.  What exact error are you getting?

Comment: i have no error. after serialize my paper and conerting to svg i get empty svg file (only definition), and $jsnser variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a soltion.
i have notices on git that there are some pulls requests, so after checking in one of them was an anwser for my question. 
here are details: https://github.com/jspies/raphael.serialize/pull/3/commits

however what is needed to be added is:

```
 if( node.node.style.display == "none" ) break;
```

under every case of node.type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Raphaël, but maybe some of the nodes don't have a `style` property.

Try something like:

```
if (node && node.type && (node.style || {}).display !== "none") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i have tried but i still get elemets on my svg that should be hidden. i checked raphael.js source and there is property style. Line 1547, 1551, 1572